# Где хранить данные своего web-приложения?

Tags: веб-программирование, хранение-данных

У меня есть web-приложение (html css react js), суть приложения в создании заметок.

Пользователь пишет свой текст добавляет какое-то форматирование и возможно картинки.

Мне же нужно сохранять все заметки пользователя на каком-нибудь сервере и подгружать всю информацию каждый раз, когда пользователь авторизируется в моем web-приложении.

В сети тонна информации, как сверстать web-приложение или полноценный сайт, но нет понятной инфы где хранить данные.

Я слышал про sql, но опять же не смог найти простой и понятный гайд по тому как её использовать с web.

Буду очень благодарен, если скинете ссылку на какой-нибудь курс или статью по моей проблеме. Можно на английском.

Comment: Вам бы сначало решить вопрос с авторизацией

Comment: На стандартном хостинге стоит уже MySql вот её и используйте.

Comment: В кейсе или специальных для этого сайтов
--------------------------------
Можно в *облаке*, или же у себя на *компе*, как ты сказал и в *sql.*

Comment: Где хранить данные? В базе данных! `MySQL`, `Mongoose`. Если у вас большое приложение, то конечно можно выбрать `MySQL`, если у вас довольно примитивное приложение с небольшой логикой, то можно `Mongoose`. Думаю авторизация у вас будет служить синхронизацией между устройствами, если же вам это не нужно и вы единожды хотите сохранять информацию на устройстве пользователя, то можно сохранить в - `localStorage`, `IndexedDB`. Всё зависит от ваших потребностей и роста приложения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотря какие у вас данные и какую задачу вы решаете этим

1. В переменной в общей области видимости
2. [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) - key - value хранилище у пользователя в браузере
3. [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) - классическая база данных локально в браузере
4. Реализовывать логику на сервере, там куча разных решений на любой вкус и цвет